# could this remove method for Linkedlist work?

Tags: java, linked-list

I asked my friends about this and they said you can never take the current to the previous node and when I asked why they didn't give me a clear reason can anyone help me?

```
//here is the signature of the method;
public void remove (){
    Node<T> tmp = null;
    tmp.next = head;
    // I want to delete the current by the way!;
    while (tmp.next != current)
        tmp = tmp.next;
    tmp.next = current.next;
    //now am taking the current to the node before it so that it only becomes null if the linkedlist is empty;
    current=tmp;
}
```

Comment: What does 'you can never take the current to the previous node' mean?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is sound if you are looking to mutate an existing linked list and remove an element.  Although there is a lack of curly braces after the while and a NullPointException that will occur at the first tmp.next.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a `remove` method would be passed the data in the node to remove. It's unclear in your question what `current` is supposed to point to. Your code does not support removing the head of the list or empty lists (null head).

Here's a potential implementation:

```
public boolean remove(T value) {
    if (head == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (head.value.equals(value)) {
        head = head.next;
        return true;
    } else {
        Node<T> current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            if (current.next.value.equals(value)) {
                current.next = current.next.next;
                return true;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the `current` variable is supposed to end up pointing to the node before the removed node then you have a problem: what happens if you are removing the head of the list?

Comment: will I want to delete the node that the current is pointing at, and if for some reason the current == head then that means that I want to remove the head, the problem is that in my Doctor implantation he did point the head to Null if there was only one node in the linked List so I said to myself if we can do that then we can Do it this way too